The number of strings of length $n$ consisting of symbols $A,B,C$ not containing substring $CC$
So I'm wondering what is wrong with my reasoning.
Let $a_n$ be the number of strings of length $n$ in letters $A,B,C$ not containing substring $CC$.
I want to solve it like this. Let $b_n$ be the number of strings which end with $A$ or $B$ and $c_n$ be the number of strings that end with $C$.
For a string of length $n-1$ that ends with $A$ or $B$ there is three choices to append a symbol. For a string of same length but ends with $C$ there are two choices so we have $a_n=3b_{n-1}+2c_{n-1}$. Since $b_{n-1}+c_{n-1}=a_{n-1}$ and $b_{n-1}=a_{n-2}$ we have $a_n=3b_{n-1}+2c_{n-1}=a_{n-2}+2a_{n-1}$
I'm not sure but I think the correct solution is $a_n=2a_{n-2}+2a_{n-1}$. The answer is of no matter though, I would like to know what is wrong my reasoning.
Explanation of my reasoning. So first I try calculate $a_n$ from $b_{n-1}$ and $c_{n-1}$. I consider the strings of length $n-1$, they either end with $A$, $B$ or $C$. If they end with $A$ or $B$ then I have $3$ choices to append a symbol to the string so it becomes string of length $n$ thus there $3b_{n-1}$ strings where the second to last symbol is $A$ or $B$.
Further, consider the string of length $n-1$ where the last symbol is $C$. Then there are two choices append a symbol so there are $2c_{n-1}$ strings where the second to last symbol is C.
Then I add up the strings which the second to last symbol is $A$ or $B$ and $C$ and get $a_n=3b_{n-1}+2c_{n-1}$.

You first have to write $b_n$ and $c_n$ in terms of recurrence relations, and then conclude the recurrence relation for $a_n$ using them.

I wrote the derivation as an answer below. But as you more specifically wonder what is wrong in your reasoning, please explain your reasoning in more detail so that we can point it out. How did you deduce $a_n = a_{n-2} + 2a_{n-1}$ ?

I wrote it out.

The mistake is at $b_{n-1} = a_{n-2}$. Why do you think that this equality holds?

It should be $b_{n-1}=2a_{n-2}$ I don't know what I was thinking lol

With that correction, you obtain the correct recurrent relation, right?

Here is a systematic approach with a convenient notation which helps to derive recurrence relations of this kind.
We count the number $a_n$ of valid strings of length $n$ from the set $\{A,B,C\}$, i.e. strings which do not contain $CC$. We do so   by partitioning  them according to their matching length with the initial parts of   the  bad string $CC$.
We consider
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{a_n=a^{[\emptyset]}_n+a^{[C]}_n}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

The  number $a^{[\emptyset]}_n$ counts the valid strings of  length  $n$   which do not start with the   rightmost character  of  the       bad   word $CC$,  i.e.  start  with $A$ or $B$.

The  number $a^{[C]}_n$ counts the valid strings of length  $n$  which do  start with the   rightmost character  of  the       bad   word $CC$,  i.e.  $C$.


We  get a    relationship  between valid strings of length $n$  with  those of length  $n+1$  as follows:

If a word counted  by $a^{[\emptyset]}_n$ is appended by $A$ or $B$ from the left it contributes to $a^{[\emptyset]}_{n+1}$. If it is appended by $C$ from the left it contributes to $a^{[C]}_{n+1}$.

If a word counted  by $a^{[C]}_n$ is appended by $A$ or $B$ from the left it contributes to $a^{[\emptyset]}_{n+1}$. Appending from the left by $C$  is not allowed since then we have an invalid string starting with $CC$.


This relationship can be written as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{a^{[\emptyset]}_{n+1}}&\color{blue}{=2a^{[\emptyset]}_{n}+2a^{[C]}_{n}}\tag{2}\\
\color{blue}{a^{[C]}_{n+1}}&\color{blue}{=a^{[\emptyset]}_n}\tag{3}
\end{align*}
We can now derive a recurrence relation from (1) - (3):

We obtain for $n\geq 1$:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{a_{n+1}}&=a^{[\emptyset]}_{n+1}+a^{[C]}_{n+1}\tag{$ \to (1)$}\\
&=\left(2a^{[\emptyset]}_{n}+2a^{[C]}_{n}\right)+\left(a^{[\emptyset]}_{n}\right)
\tag{$\to (2),(3)$}\\
&=2a_{n}+\left(2a^{[\emptyset]}_{n-1}+2a^{[C]}_{n-1}\right)\tag{$\to (1),(2)$}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=2a_n+2a_{n-1}}\tag{$\to (1)$}
\end{align*}
as given in the other answer.


I think you wanted to mean "counts the valid strings of length n
which do not start with the leftmost character of the bad word CC" instead of "counts the valid strings of length n
which do not start with the rightmost character of the bad word CC"

because you added letters A,B,C from the left side

i could not understand why di you write "rightmost character of the bad word CC"

@NotaSalmonFish: We consider valid strings by appending characters from the left until we have the wanted length $n$. Let's put a bit more asymmetry by assuming the bad word is $CB$. Since we expand a string $XXX$ at the left side and want to avoid $CBXXX$ we have to consider the rightmost letter $B$ of the bad word first.

thanks a lot for it

@NotaSalmonFish: You're welcome. :-)

Simple reasoning gives us $b_n = 2 (b_{n-1} + c_{n-1})$ and $c_n = b_{n-1}$.
We therefore have
$\begin{align}
a_n &= b_n + c_n \\
&= 2( b_{n-1} + c_{n-1} ) + b_{n-1} \\
&= 2( b_{n-1} + c_{n-1} ) + 2( b_{n-2} + c_{n-2} ) \\
&= 2a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-2}.
\end{align}$
